# What are the chances that you are on plane that has an incident?

Tags: safety

[ICAO Annex 13](http://www.iprr.org/manuals/Annex13.html) defines an "incident" as

> An occurrence, other than an accident, associated with the operation of an aircraft which affects or could affect the safety of operation.

Is there good record keeping about incidents globally? Not like [Aviation Global Incident Map](http://aviation.globalincidentmap.com/) which only really only lists accidents and some airport issues.

For completeness, the same document defines an "accident" to be

> An occurrence associated with the operation of an aircraft which takes place between the time any person boards the aircraft with the intention of flight until such time as all such persons have disembarked, in which (a) a person is fatally or seriously injured [...], (b) the aircraft sustains damage or structural failure [...] or (c) the aircraft is missing or is completely inaccessible.

Only incidents that an airliner pilot is aware mid-flight and can do something about -this a start to follow-up.  question. Exact likelihood is not important- is it 10% or 20%. For passengers, the likelihood is not important since pilots handle mainly well.

Comment: This is very difficult to answer because your definition of incident is quite vague. What is standard flying? Is a go around, instructed by Air Traffic Control because the runway is occupied, standard flying? Or when the go around was decided by the flight crew because the approach was unstable? Is an inoperative auto-thrust system, which results in manual thrust setting throughout the flight, standard flying? And if it fails in flight?

Comment: There is avherald.com but it doesn't record *all* incidents

Comment: although accident is quite simple to define (let's say "at least one casualty"), incident is not. For your car, do you consider a failure in windscreen wiper on a sunny day as an incident?

Comment: @ManuH "Accident" is defined by Annex 13 of the Convention on International Civil Aviation: we don't need to make up our own definition.

Comment: @DeltaLima I've removed the vagueness by inserting the ICAO definition of "incident".

Comment: The chance of any given passenger being involved in an incident is is both approximately zero, and also far less than the chance of being involved in an incident getting to-and-from the airport or just walking through the terminal.

Comment: Define yourself more precisely please. Is the question about "major injuries" or "fatalities", then you can ask precisely how many fatalities do you have per 10^9 miles or per 10^6 flights or similar. The number is very low. Also, it depends on the type of plane. If you consider military flights (including missions), the rate is orders of magnitude higher.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "incident" is still vaguely (or at least very broadly) defined. If a pilot has a sneezing fit that could meet the ICAO definition of incident (it *could affect* the safety of operation as they can't very well safely operate a plane if I'm having a sneezing fit, can they? Further in a two-person crew operation it could significantly distract the other pilot...)

Comment: Regardless of your definition of "incident", there are quite simply too many factors in play. The type of the aircraft, the pilots, the region you're flying from/to, etc... all play a role in what "incidents" may happen and how likely they are to happen. Unfortunately, there isn't some blanket statement we can make in this area, although you can feel free to make your own judgement based off historic data.

Comment: This can't really be answered because many incidents are only identified long after the fact (eg. [a recent report on a problem with a Jetconnect B737](http://avherald.com/h?article=483b700e&opt=0), where the actual incident took place sometime between when the aircraft was assembled in 2011, and when the damage was found in 2013).  For that matter, many incidents are never identified.

Comment: I'm voting to leave closed for basically the reasons that bluefish states: Any answer will depend _way_ too much on other factors (not the least of these being the pilot(s) [including experience,] aircraft type, location, maintenance, airline, and weather.)

Comment: What an incident is is defined in ICAO DOC 9156, the accident and incident reporting manual. See [link] http://aviationwiki.net/index.php?title=File:ICAO_Doc_9156_ADREP_Manual.pdf Incidents are events like engine failures, fires, decompression etc. The ICAO seems to keep a database of incidents, with this information one can calculate the probability of being in an incident, given the time one spends on board airplanes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby my point is that incident is difficult to define althought it is quite easy to agree on a definition of accident. I didn't know there was already a definition somewhere. I link the [convention](http://www.icao.int/publications/pages/doc7300.aspx).

Comment: I see you've edited the question to try to be more on-topic. You might find it is easier to be on-topic by rewording the question as "how many incidents are there annually", or something along those lines. You can then compare that to the number of flights annually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a global compilation. But for Australian operations data exists to allow us to establish a likelihood of being in an incident. Accidents are so rare that it's difficult to get a reliable indicator, however if we are just measuring reported *incidents* I believe we could get somewhere.

The Australian Transport Safety Bureau (ATSB) has published an ["Aviation Occurrence Statistics" report](http://www.atsb.gov.au/media/5474110/ar2014084_final.pdf) covering 2004-2013.

Let's focus on high-capacity RPT operations, because lets face it, that is probably what most people are interested in.

According to the report, in 2013, there were 597,000 departures of Australian-registered high capacity RPT or charter flights (unfortunately the report doesn't seem to split it into RPT only, possibly because we have a lot of high-capacity charter flights to the mines). In the same year there were 3292 reported incidents to the ATSB and 2 accidents. Therefore I would conclude that if in 2013 you boarded an Australian-registered high-capacity RPT or charter flight, your chances of being in a *reported* incident were around 0.5%, and chances of being are an accident is 0.06%. The incident percentage is approximately the same for the couple of years prior, so I am confident that this remains around about the mark today - though I would not consider the accident rate to be reliable because there were so few.

The incidents cited in this data vary from loss of separation to a pilot being sick to birdstrikes.

Have a read of the report but before you take it as gospel, keep in mind, as they say, "there are lies, damn lies, and statistics!"